# Python 3: How to compare two tuples and find similar values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have two dictionaries: `(1)Inventory and (2)Items`
Under these dictionaries are tuples which are added using user's input.

```
 dict_inventory = {('fruits', ['apple','mango'])

 dict_items = {('apple', [3, 5])
    ('mango', [4, 6])}
```

How do I compare the two and to match similar values which are `apple` and `mango`

My code is not printing anything:

```
for itemA in dict_inventory.values():
    for itemB in dict_items.keys():
        if itemA == itemB:
            print("Match!")
```

Comment: Please define your dictionaries precisely, e.g. `print(dict_inventory)`. Without seeing how these are defined, it's difficult for us to help.

Comment: Do you need to use two dictionaries? You could just combine them into a nested dictionary.

Comment: @jpp I started Python just a week ago. I'm really not sure what you mean, but these dictionaries are also added using user's input. But I will edit the post and add the codes what I think you may need.

Comment: @Tanmayjain Yes.

Comment: can you edit your question and put in sample (1) Inventory and (2)Items dictionary

Comment: @Tanmayjain I have edited my question. Is it now alright?

Comment: dictionary contains `{key: value }` what is key here ?

Comment: @artomason I wasn't really sure how I could do that so I just separated them and maybe compare them instead. I'm sorry, I'm just a week old in Python

Comment: @Geni-sama I understand, please see my answer below.

Comment: @Tanmayjain I suppose the key in 'dict_inventory' is the 'fruits' and its values are the 'apples' and 'mango' while they keys in 'dict_items' are the 'apple' and 'mango' and the values are 3,4,5 and 6

Comment: @Geni-sama hmm I thought so, I think artomason has already answered your question. If you are still looking for something else feel free to comment.

Comment: @Tanmayjain Thank you. I am looking for a lot of things and still researching on how I could polish and simplify my codes. But I'm taking it one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original `for-loop` was getting the values from the inventory dictionary as a `list` rather than a `string` when you iterated through the values. Since it returned a list, you will need to iterate through those values as well. This should get you running:

```
inventory = {
    "fruits": ["apples", "mangos",]
}

items = {
    "apples": [3, 5],
    "mangos": [4, 6],
}

for value in inventory.values():
    for item_a in value:
        if item_a in items.keys():
            print("Match!")
```

However, you could just merge the two dictionaries.

```
inventory = {
    "fruits": {
        "apples": [3, 5],
        "mangos": [4, 6],
    }
}
```

Comment: This answered my question! I just wonder how was this correct and mine wasn't?

Comment: I saw your explanation late.

Comment: @Geni-sama do you literally have this written in your code `dict_inventory = {('fruits', ['apple','mango'])is <class 'tuple'>}` ? if so its wrong python should have given you SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Geni-sama if this answered your question, please considering accepting it.

Comment: @Tanmayjain No. It is only the output. Here is my full code: https://pastebin.com/fkkxiwCJ It's messy so I didn't showed it here to avoid confusion

Comment: @artomason Will do. Thank you guys for the help.